# Is it possible to track user error in Trigger.io using New Relic (or a similar)

Tags: trigger.io, newrelic

New relic offers browser performance/error monitoring as well as app motoring for iOS, Android and hybird Titanium apps.

I would like to do something similar with my Trigger.io app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic does not currently support Trigger.io.  As you stated they currently support native iOS and Android applications along with Titanium applications.  The best bet is to ask on their forums and try and get it as a feature request for a possible future release.  This can be done at https://discuss.newrelic.com/